# Fetch Mails From MS-Exchange Using Graph API

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-exchange

Can someone help me out that how I can fetch mails from Exchange User's mailbox using Microsoft Graph API?

Graph API is working fine for the online exchange users **(O365)** not for offline users **(local users)**, but there is another problem too. Graph API provides Rest APIs by using which we can access each mailbox individually which will become very server loaded work if more than **1000K** mailbox need to be scanned one by one and also a time taking process.

I want to fetch scan **all user's mailbox at once** both offline and online. Just like Microsoft **Powershell** do.

Is there any way to do so?

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to get local mailboxes from an on-prem Exchange server using Graph.

Comment: I partially agree with @bluuf. Incase if you're term local mailbox is meant for on-prem mailboxes then its doable. In such scenario, you can still make use of Microsoft Graph, incase if you're having Exchange hybrid setup (Exchange Online + onprem) and meet the requirements then you can make the use of the mailbox items from both the environments. You can get it [started from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/hybrid-rest-support), check the requirements, do the necessary setup and the above functionality is in preview.